# how to custom react-flow control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-flow

I have a person project,in this project,i used react-flow、react,
i wish to make a custom control replace original control, includes zoomIn、zoomOut、fit、percent、add nodes and the element position is bottom right. add nodes can open side or drawer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⬇️is my custom control and some control APIs realized code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWhpA.png)

⬇️is my implementations code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfxvC.png)

Comment: Maybe you have a better idea, please share it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).